# Pass by reference MatLab

Tags: matlab, scope

I am working on a GUI in matlab and I'm using a variable called `top` to store everything. I have an update function that is in one area that updates other areas, but I don't like that it bleeds my `top`variable into it, but I can't find a way to just pass the reference to the top variable so that it can still mutate what needs to be mutated.

Is there a pass by reference or some equivalent in matlab?

Edit:
For example I want to move this function to a place where `top` is inaccessible, but it needs a current `top` to do it's job, if I were to pass `top` by reference to the file that makes this I could still access `top`:

```
function update_Screens_Callback(~,~)
    % Look to see if each check box is marked and if it is add it to seen.
    seen = [];
    for i=1:10
        top.screens{i}.Visible='off';
    end
    for i=1:4
        if(top.sets{i,1}.Value==top.sets{i,1}.Max)
            seen = [seen i];
        end
    end
    for i=1:6
        if(top.sets{i,2}.Value==top.sets{i,2}.Max)
            seen = [seen,i+4];
        end
    end
    tmp = size(seen);
    tmp = tmp(2);
    sizes = getSizes(tmp);
    for i=1:tmp
        index = seen(i);
        top.screens{index}.Visible = 'on';
        top.screens{index}.Position = sizes{i};
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding what the question is. Please provide some example code that illustrates the issue you're having. See [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance.

Comment: @excaza Sorry I didn't want to make the post too long, I added it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, function calls in MATLAB pass arguments by value, but there is an exception where internal optimization effectively results in passes by reference. When a function returns an argument - e.g. a large matrix - as in

```
function top = updategui(top)
    top(42, 42) = 42;
end
```

*and* if you assign the argument as part of the invocation as in `x = updategui(x);`,  MATLAB will recognize that copying `top` is unnecessary and will pass `top` by reference.

However, I don't think "passing by reference" will help you solve your specific problem. Much of your question sounds more related to *scope* than to abstraction or passing by reference vs. by value. For example, it is common practice to share variables across GUI components via [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. I only started Matlab on Tuesday, so I'm new to it's practices. You answered the question I should've asked!

Comment: Great to hear, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Such behavior can be achieved in object oriented matlab. Just create an object as subclass from handle. (Here's some [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html))

```
classdef myHelper < handle 
   properties
      x
   end
end
```

you can then use it like:

```
a = myHelper
a.x = important_data
```

and give a to all your functions.

As example:

```
a = myHelper
a.x = 1
b = a
b.x = 2
a.x
```

you will see that `a` was also updated.